# Apache - caching responses from app server

Tags: caching, apache, reverse-proxy

I have an web application server sitting behind Apache 2.4.2 in a reverse proxy configuration.  The app server returns a response including the following headers:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 01:21:30 GMT
```

I have Apache 2.4.2 working as a reverse proxy in front of this application server and want to cache responses from the application server.  I can't modify the application server.  How do I do this in Apache?  I was hopeful for CacheStoreExpired and CacheIgnoreCacheControl but they don't help here because Apache makes a conditional request to the backend - and the app server always wants to refresh the cache with something new that expires 'now'.  I wonder if I can rewrite the headers returned from the application server?

I am using mod_cache (to no avail) with this config:

```
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/"

CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheStoreNoStore On
CacheStoreExpired On

CacheStaleOnError on

LogLevel debug
CacheHeader on
CacheDetailHeader on

CacheDefaultExpire 120
CacheMaxExpire 120

SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

Apache's debug log is a bit worrying, too:

```
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:52.113857 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] cache_storage.c(624): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00698: cache: Key for entity /browse?(null) is http://192.168.4.189:80/browse?, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:52.113857 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(159): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00750: Adding CACHE_SAVE filter for /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:52.113857 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(169): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00751: Adding CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter for /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.503049 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(1190): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00769: cache: Caching url: /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.503049 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(1196): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00770: cache: Removing CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.643529 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(1318): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00737: commit_entity: Headers and body for URL http://192.168.4.189:80/browse? cached., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] cache_storage.c(624): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00698: cache: Key for entity /browse?(null) is http://192.168.4.189:80/browse?, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(569): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00709: Recalled cached URL info header http://192.168.4.189:80/browse?, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(865): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00720: Recalled headers for URL http://192.168.4.189:80/browse?, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] cache_storage.c(320): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00695: Cached response for /browse isn't fresh.  Adding/replacing conditional request headers., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(159): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00750: Adding CACHE_SAVE filter for /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:53.799618 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(169): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00751: Adding CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter for /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.235637 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(1190): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00769: cache: Caching url: /browse, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.235637 2013] [cache:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache.c(1196): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00770: cache: Removing CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.298072 2013] [cache_disk:warn] [pid 2824:tid 964] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00699: rename tempfile to file failed: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/aptmpcJvfPV -> C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/A/3/xM0hz_t8XPQaojszgaGA.data, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.298072 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(617): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00711: Deleting C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/A/3/xM0hz_t8XPQaojszgaGA.header from cache., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.298072 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(634): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00713: Deleting C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/A/3/xM0hz_t8XPQaojszgaGA.data from cache., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.298072 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(674): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00715: Deleting directory C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cache/A/3 from cache, referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
[Fri Jan 04 16:27:55.298072 2013] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 2824:tid 964] mod_cache_disk.c(1313): [client 192.168.4.36:51783] AH00736: commit_entity: URL 'http://192.168.4.189:80/browse?' not cached due to earlier disk error., referer: http://192.168.4.189/browse
```

Comment: Hi dave, did you figured out what's wrong in your configuration? Did you fixed the error `not cached due to earlier disk error`?

Comment: I gave up! I think the 'rename tempfile to file failed' warning is a bug in Apache on Windows (http://goo.gl/HPSb4).  Mod_headers stripped the anti-cache response from the origin server (Header unset Expires) which let Apache start caching but then mod_expires couldn't set a computed expiration, nor could I re-insert a no-cache header to responses served from the cache (to prevent caching elsewhere in the web). Then Apache served something from its cache when a browser's request contained max-age=0 (spooked me).  Ultimately I realised I need caching in the application layer, not HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with mod_cache

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html

Please consider also to add:

```
CacheIgnoreQueryString On
```

Requests with query string parameters are not cached by default.

Looking at your log, there is an error in the last line: `not cached due to earlier disk error`.
May be your apache server does not have correct permission to write into cache directory, or your disk is full...
You should double check if the apache memcache directory is correctly created.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I am using mod_cache but what configuration would you suggest?  (Edited original post to show my current config.)

Comment: Your configuration it seems correct. In order to understand what's wrong I need also the HTTP header returned by apache's response

Comment: That actually is the header returned by Apache.  Perhaps more interestingly I'll add an excerpt from Apache's debug log showing the request;fetch;cache;invalidate;refetch;serve caused by a single browser's request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CacheIgnoreHeaders to ignore unwanted headers from the backend app server: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheignoreheaders

For example:

```
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie Cookie Cookie2 X-Forwarded-For X-Forwarded-Host
```